# Memory Leaks while making Oracle.DataAccess.dll method calls

Tags: entity-framework, oracle11g, dispose, odp.net, clob

We have a WCF web service which uses Entity Framework as the ORM for data access.
The oracle database we are using is Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production.
The entity framework uses Oracle.DataAccess.dll to connect to the database. The Oracle.DataAccess version used is 2.112.3.0.
We are getting Memory leaks when making calls to Oracle database.
On investigation,
The hang dumps show that 4.35% to 8.33% of threads were blocked on OraOCIEI11!slgtd() calls.
2.20% of threads are blocked due to a leaked critical section (the thread owning the critical section is the one processing the OraOps11w!ssmem_free() call). The calls that are waiting are:
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OpsDac.Dispose()
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OpsDac.Read()
We would like to know if calls waiting on OraOCIEI11 functions are expected?

Also we have another critical section in locked state with the owning thread processing the oracle call OraOCIEI11!slgtd().
We saw that the Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.Read() method is taking time while retrieving Clob data from the database.

Also,
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.Dispose calls OraOps11w!ssmem_free() that hasn’t returned. This method is being called internally by the Entity Framework after making use of the CompiledQuery Feature of EF.

Is this issue related to the dll version we are using?
Are there any methods we can try to avoid the leaked critical section and the memory leaks?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Regards,
Manish

Comment: Does the problem go away when you use ODP.NET 12.1? Also make sure you are calling Close() and Dispose() on the connection objects. The garbage collector won't know that a connection object controls as much resources as it does.

Comment: Are you using OracleTimeStamp / DateTimeOffset columns?

Comment: No. We are not using OracleTimeStamp.

Comment: We have changed our code to explicitly call Close() and Dispose() methods on the readers, commands and connections and on Clobtype as well.

Comment: @ChristianShay : I can not change the ODP.Net version for our project.

Answer (score 0):

If there are CLOBs involved, then they are disposable objects. Depending on how you are getting the data back, you may be responsible for manually disposing the result. All their examples for .Net acutally show .Close and .Dispose called once data is processed out of the object. Dispose() should handle both, but their docs specifically show both. Disposing alone of the CLOBs fixed our out of memory exception and memory leaks. This is the Orcale ODP.Net documentation and CLOB example: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E20434_01/doc/win.112/e23174/OracleClobClass.htm

Our original code
IDataRecord record; //Initialized from .Read()

obj o = record[columnName];

This code does return the CLOB value but leaks the memory associated with it.

Replaced with

```
o = ((OracleDataReader)record).GetOracleValue(record.GetOrdinal(columnName));
if (o is OracleString)
{
    if (((OracleString)o).IsNull)
    {
        return defaultValue
    }
    return o.ToString();
}
else if (o is OracleClob)
{
    OracleClob clob = (OracleClob)o;
    try
    {
        if (clob.IsNull)
        {
            return defaultValue;
        }
        return clob.Value;
    }
    finally
    {
        clob.Close();
        clob.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Code format will vary based on language (C# here) and interface.